# Jquery slider and expanding backgrounds

Tags: jquery, dhtml, jcarousel

I can't figure out whats causing the slider on this site to overlay over the page below it with a white background. Testing in IE8 and it doesn't look right. Its working fine the in the current version of Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone mind taking a look at [this site](http://www.startronics.co/magento/)?

Comment: tell the world to stop using IE

Comment: I wish that was an option :D or someone at MS should realize that they  don't make the standards D:

Comment: That is an option.  You have the power to change the world.  Some of the agencies I work with have stopped supporting IE, unless they pay a huge premium.  IE has cost developers tons of money trying to be compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed if you remove `width:1920px;` from following style:

```
<div class="panel" style="height: 985px; display: block; opacity: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1920px;">
```

Comment: Im not sure where thats coming from, I didn't define it in any css. My belief is that is being created from one of the scripts but I dont see where.